# Display ads on responsive site

Tags: adsense

I made place(with placehold.it) for ads from AdSense. Web site is made with bootstrap, so it's responsive. Can I resize ads? I did this:

[image]

Comment: Just a reminder.. you should first try it before you ask a question. Only ask a question if you face to a programming issue or something.

Comment: @C0dekid Maybe they'll ban me?

Comment: I don't think they will ban you, but they do have some requirements. Learn more: [About responsive ad units](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689?hl=en)

Comment: They will not ban you, the can downvote your post and moderators can close your question for being too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are step by step to create responsive ads from Google.

See here https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3543893?hl=en